# Код страницы - в переменную

Tags: curl, php, синтаксический-анализ

Как получить код страницы example.com в переменную, для дальнейшего парсинга?

Comment:     file_get_content()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents()`, либо использовать `curl` если на удаленном сервере стоит проверка рефера.